# Rails - Reference to id of a model with underscore in belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my problem:
I have 2 models, `Competition` and `Competitiontype` linked with a `belongs_to`/`has_many` relationship. Trying to transpose Michael Hartl's excellent tutorial (with users / micro posts), I successfully test that my `Competition` model is valid when building it with:

```
@competition = Competition.new(name: "Test", competitiontype_id: @competition_type.id)
```

within the model tests.

But when I try to be a bit more "idiomatically correct" using:

```
@competition = @competition_type.competitions.build(name: "Test")
```

I get an error regarding the 'unknown attribute competition_type_id'
I have a feeling that I am getting mixed up with underscores, but the 2 formulations are supposed to be equivalent.

Any clue on how I could correct that?

It is a very particular issue difficult to express with a few keywords, I am really sorry if this has been already talked about somewhere else (I didn't find it).

Comment: Is your `belongs_to` anything more than just `belongs_to :competition_type`? Also I edited `competition_type` to `Competitiontype`, since the former is not a valid class name. Please correct it if it is instead `CompetitionType`

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: If your have `CompetitionType` as class name then you need to rename `competitiontype_id` to `competition_type_id` in `competitions` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in that the `competitiontype_id` is mistyped without underscore. It should be `competition_type_id`. This can be seen from the first code

```
@competition = Competition.new(name: "Test", competitiontype_id: @competition_type.id)
```

Because of that it can't be found when searching for competitions belonging to competition_type.

Just rename the column `competitiontype_id` to `competition_type_id` and refactor the first code snippet posted to use underscore format.

Comment: I renamed the column with a new migration, adjusted all fixtures and tests and it is now working perfectly for both methods.